# Why? Can't call custom file phtml to list.phtml?

Tags: magento-1.9, catalog, custom-block, list.phtml, list-view

In controller

```
....
      $this->_initAction();
//        $this->loadLayout();
        $update = $this->getLayout()->getUpdate();
        $update->addHandle('default');
        $this->addActionLayoutHandles();
        $update ->removeHandle('shopbybrand_index_view')
                ->addHandle('catalog_category_default')
                ->addHandle('catalog_category_view')
                ->addHandle('catalog_category_layered')

                ->addHandle('shopbybrand_index_view');
        $this->loadLayoutUpdates();
        $this->generateLayoutXml();
        $this->generateLayoutBlocks();
        $this->_isLayoutLoaded = true;
....
```

in list.phtml:

```
   <?php
$block = Mage::app()->getLayout()->createBlock('shopbybrand/productinfo')->setTemplate('shopbybrand/namebrand.phtml')->toHtml();
echo $block;
?>
```

But nothing show, same code in view.phtml, block shows fine!!

```
+/

    Getproduct in productinfo.php

        public function getProduct(){
                 $product = Mage::registry('current_product');
                return $product;
            }
```

Comment: Depends what the contents of the `shopbybrand/productinfo` does. If it's working on the product page it might be that it's pulling in information from `Mage::registry('current_product')` and doesn't display anything unless this is set.

Comment: yes I find 
public function getProduct(){
        $product = Mage::registry('current_product');
        return $product;
    }
so what can i do?

Answer (score 0):

Please remove $this->loadLayout();

1. If you add your handle before you call $this->loadLayout() from a controller it's too soon.
2. If you add your handle after you call $this->loadLayout() it's too late.

More information [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3463030/magento-use-own-handle-in-widgets-doesnt-work)